# Where can I see my stored data using FileSystem API?

Tags: html, google-chrome, filesystems, storing-data

I've successfully stored data using FILESYSTEM API provided by HTML5. But I don't know where I could identify the file in my local repository so that I can backup the data I stored. I have also check my root directory of application in the server (Tomcat 7.0), but I couldn't find the file. While using chrome developer tools, I checked the data is storing successfully.

The Code goes like this:

```
 window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

            function onInitFs(fs)
            {
                fs.root.getFile('fpslog.txt', {create: false}, function(fileEntry) {

                        // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
                        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

                          fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); // Start write position at EOF.

                             fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                              console.log('Write completed.');
                            };

                              fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                              console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
                            };

                          // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
                          var blob = new Blob(['Hello World'], {type: 'text/plain'});

                          fileWriter.write(blob);

                        }, errorHandler);

                      }, errorHandler);

            }

            window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

and the ERROR function:

```
function errorHandler(e) {
                  var msg = '';

                  switch (e.code) {
                    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                      break;
                    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                      break;
                    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                      break;
                    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                      break;
                    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                      break;
                    default:
                      msg = 'Unknown Error';
                      break;
                  };

                  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
                }
```

In developer tools, I did see no error print rather it is saying 'write completed', which means i'm able to create file somewhere and storing the data. I want to get to access that data to view. As already the tutorial mentioned, I don't see any file created in root folder. Any Help Please.

Comment: @E-Riz, I want to know how to store floating point numbers, integer values using Blob. How can I add space between one insert and other insert of Blob data into the file. Any help please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also view the files using the root directory's `filesystem:` URL. Open 
`filesystem:<YOUR_ORIGIN>/temporary/` in the address bar, replacing  with the origin your app is running off of (e.g. "http://stackoverflow.com").

You can also enable "FileSystem inspection" in the DevTools under experiments. This may also require you to "Enable Experimental DevTools features" in `about:flags`.

Comment: How can I store integers and decimals dynamically with Blob using FileSystem API? A sample snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Couldn't you store numbers in a .txt/.json file and read them back using the `Filesystem` and `FileReader` APIs? Also, you could store a serialized array of values, and `JSON.parse()` the data back into JS after reading it.

Comment: I just want to store the values dynamically in local repository. Later, I want those values to plot the graph. For this scenario, I couldn't  find any solution. Using FileSystem API, while storing the values dynamically which are returned values from a javascript function, Blob is storing the whole function rather storing the values returned from function. 
for ex: var blob = new Blob(['The values are: ', +getValues()]);
fliewriter.write(blob);
In the above scenario, rather storing values it is storing (function getvalues() { return value; } ). Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found out way, using google chrome [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-filesystem-explorer/nhnjmpbdkieehidddbaeajffijockaea) which helps you to view the content of filesystem API of HTML5.